# How can I determine the type of a shape on a worksheet containing a variety of Shapes?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to  loop through the shapes on my worksheet to determine if they are a DropDown, then if a particular dropdown is located on a specific row. The worksheet contains many checkboxes and dropdowns.
I am creating the dropdowns with a loop, as below:

```
 wsBank.DropDowns.Add(Range(AnsPositionAddress).Left, Range(AnsPositionAddress).Top, Range(AnsPositionAddress).Width, Range(AnsPositionAddress).Height).Select
With Selection
    '.ListFillRange = AnsPositionRng.Offset(0, 1)
    '.LinkedCell = AnsPositionRng.Offset(0, 1)
    .DropDownLines = 4
    .Display3DShading = False
    .Name = "QuestionDrop" & QuizQuestionNumber
    .OnAction = "recordAnswer"
End With

Number = 1
For Each Q In AnsRng
    wsBank.DropDowns("QuestionDrop" & QuizQuestionNumber).AddItem Number & " -  " & Q
    Number = Number + 1
Next Q
```

And I am creating the check boxes as below:

```
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Range(chkbxAddress).Left, Range(chkbxAddress).Top, Range(chkbxAddress).Width, Range(chkbxAddress).Height).Select
With Selection
    .Caption = ""
    .Value = xlOff
    .LinkedCell = AnsPositionRng.Offset(0, -4).Address
    .Display3DShading = True
End With
```

If a particular cell in a range contains 'True', then I would like to find the dropdown that is held on that same row, so I was going to loop through the shapes, determine if the shape is a dropdown, then check its BottomRight Cell property to see if it matched the row that contains 'True'.
Is this possible? I got so far as:

```
 wsBank.Activate
With wsBank
    IndicatorLstRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set IndicatorRng = wsBank.Range("B4:B" & IndicatorLstRow)
End With

For Each c In IndicatorRng
    If c = "True" Then
        QuestionRow = c.Row

            For Each ComboShape In wsBank.Shapes
               test = ComboShape.Type
            Next ComboShape

    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. First find the cell which contains "True". That will give you the cell address and from that you will get the cell row. Next simply loop through the shapes and find their `.TopLeftCell` and from that get the row and see if it matches.

Here is an example (**UNTESTED**)

```
Dim shp As Shape

For Each c In IndicatorRng
    If c = "True" Then
        QuestionRow = c.Row
        For Each shp In wsBank.Shapes
            If shp.Type = 8 And shp.Name Like "Drop*" Then
                If shp.TopLeftCell.Row = QuestionRow Then
                    '
                    '~~> Rest of the code
                    '
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Thank you very much Siddharth, that helps a lot! I was running something similar to what 'Gary's Student' has written below and was seeing a shape type 8, but since i had both check boxes and dropdowns on thw worksheets, it threw me off. Thanks aagin!

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
Sub IdentifyShapes()
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        MsgBox s.Type & vbCrLf & s.Name
    Next s
End Sub
```

You will find that drop-downs for Data Validation are type **8** and have names like **Drop Down 1**

 Experimentation will yield the types for all the Shapes on your Sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gary's Student!